# Weird laptop fan sound

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I just bought a new laptop - SAMSUNG Series 3 NP350V5C-T01US, installed ubuntu 12.10. Everything is ok, except a very annoying sound produced by the fan. If it would be just a constant sound, I mean the same sound all the time, it would be acceptable. But I hear a raising and lowering sound, it seems the speed of the fan is bigger and lower, bigger and lower. The cycle is several seconds. So annoying...

I have tried an opensource video driver, proprietary drivers (stable and beta).
Any thought, guys?

Comment: Please add some detail: Is it the same when unplugged from mains? Have you tweaked something at the BIOS settings? nVidia or AMD? Advertised as Hybrid? CPU type?

Comment: My laptop model says that it is hybrid, AMD, i7.

Answer (score 1):

It took some time to stabilize the fan's behavior. Now no more weird sound, I think the original reason was an opensource driver of my discrete video adapter.

So probable solutions:
1) turn off the discrete video adapter;
2) install the latest proprietary driver.